# List loaded modules using gdb

Tags: gdb, windbg

Is there a way to list all the loaded modules using gdb, just like Windbg, that automatically shows all the loaded modules. Its okay if there is no one word answer, I'll be happy to work things out myself if someone could please provide me a pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>Does `ldd` from the command line tell you what you need?</strike>

Actually, scratch that idea. Try `i shared`. See http://book.opensourceproject.org.cn/embedded/embeddedprime/opensource/0136130550/ch15lev1sec3.html.

Comment: Dead Link of course

Answer (score 14):

`i sh` roughly <=> `lm` or `x *!` in WinDbg

Comment: but this only provides the start and end adress of the module, the !dumpmodule can not be used further

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Windows, and you just want to see what was loaded, you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Select the process from the list, and from the menu, select View -> Lower Pane View -> DLLs. The lower pane will then show all the DLLs used by that process.